# External Sharepoint Access (Putting Sharepoint on Back on Remote Web Workspace)

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I converted my Sharepoint installation from a single server, to a 2 server Farm, and in the process accidently disconnect SP from our Remote Web Workspace.  Before, we could access Sharepoint at https://remote.mycompany.com/sharepoint.

How can we make Sharepoint externally available again?  Using the URL https://remote.mycompany.com/sharepoint.

The other settings are providing some clues, but I do not know exactly what to do.
Here is what is already setup:

[image]

What Site/IIS settings are needed get https://remote.mycompany.com/sharepoint to work?

Answer (score 1):

Small Business Server has wizards that should be used for most of the configuration items.  Even though the standard server tools are present, they tend to break things because of the way everything is integrated on the stack.

I would recommend you re-run the remote workplace wizard.